# NIS users can not start xserver, Ubuntu 20, gdm, gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gdm

I am connected with my Ubuntu 20.04.1 machine to a NIS server and have a local user as well. Homedirectories of NIS users is mounted via NFS. Users can connect via ssh, login and find their homedirectories at the correct place. What is not working is the GUI login/usage, i.e. if I login in with an NIS user account at my machine the screen turns black for a second and brings me back to the login screen. Logging in with the local user account works fine, both via ssh and the GUI login.

Searching systemd for xserver fails, I found the following errors:

`systemd-logind: failed to get session: PID 2214 does not belong to any known session`

and

`xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 2 (Permission denied)`

The whole log file is here https://pastebin.com/ikbedqDY.

Could there be a user rights problem? I have not edited any local users/groups. The NIS user group is called `users`.

If you need more information, I will be happy to provide more!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I changed from gdm3 to lightdm and the error vanishes and everyone can login.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you install `nscd`, gdm will work as expected. I recommend that you use `unscd` because it's newer than `ncsd`.